# Query hive table and dump the large file using Beeline

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive, beeline

i am trying to dump the output of a beeline to a file but it get the "Message length exceeded: 16) error (below).

```
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
    org.apche.thrift.TApplicationExcepetion: Message length exceeded: 16
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TserviceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:505)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FectchResults(TCLService.java:492)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:355)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.SeparatedValuesOutputFormat.print(SeparatedValuesOutputFormat.java:70)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.print(BeeLine.java:1702)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:756)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:675)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:918)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execute(BeeLine.java:780)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.executeFile(BeeLine.java:760)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:729)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:468)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:451)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
    Error: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException (state=08S01, code=0)
```

Here is my beeline comment:

> beeline -u jdbc:hive2://xxxx:10000/default -n xxx -p xxx -f /frankie/query.hql --silent=true --showHeader=true --incremental=true --outputformat=tsv2 > output.tsv

and the Hive Server Version:

> Beeline version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.3 by Apache Hive

Can someone let me know how solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the actual image rather than a link, as this is preferred generally on the site.

Comment: No images. Text only. format it using ctrl+k

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post image.

Comment: No @David. No images. Text only. Something searchable and copy-able.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I have already upload images, and post it with link.

Comment: So remove them and put text instead.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz thank you for your remind.  Put it instead of text.